# SQL Command Error UPDATE "Near Syntax \ "

Tags: sql, vb.net, t-sql, exception, ado.net

What i'm trying to do is that from a ASP.NET (framework 4) a user shall be able to update an existing record in a SQL Database using the record Key. USING Visual Studio 2010 (vb)

I get an error of  Syntax near " \ ", i have 2 textboxes:
1- For the key
2-contains the information that would be sent to the SQL server in order to update such column (Control_ClosedByRev)

```
Dim Con As New SqlConnection
Dim SQL As String
Dim com As SqlCommand = Con.CreateCommand
Dim KeyID As Integer
KeyID = TextBox1_UpdateDataReview.Text

Con.ConnectionString = "Data Source=WCRDUSMJEMPR9\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=MicroDB;Integrated Security=True"
Con.Open()
SQL = "UPDATE ControlCharts set Control_ClosedByRev=" & TextBox2_UpdateDataReview.Text & " where ID_ControlCharts= " & KeyID
Dim cmd As New SqlCommand(SQL, Con)
'cmd.ExecuteScalar()
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
Label1_UpdateDataReview.Text = "Record Updated"
```

i tried changing the cmd.execute, it did not work. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You should use parameterized queries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off, this is quite vulnerable to SQL Injection -- read into that and use parameterized queries instead.

Here is some sample code to help.

```
    Con.ConnectionString = "Data Source=WCRDUSMJEMPR9\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=MicroDB;Integrated Security=True"
    Con.Open()
    SQL = "UPDATE ControlCharts set Control_ClosedByRev=@ClosedByRev where ID_ControlCharts=@Key"

    Dim cmd As New SqlCommand(SQL, Con)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ClosedByRev ", TextBox2_UpdateDataReview.Text)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Key", KeyID)
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
```

Good luck.

Comment: can you provide how the string will look like?? i use paramtized query only once for INSERT and i did not found how to use it as UPDATE.

Comment: Not sure I'm following -- see code above. Since it uses AddWithValue, it shouldn't matter.  Good luck.

Comment: it Worked, i'm learing form all this. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Try this: put "@" symbol before the the string

```
 Con.ConnectionString = @"Data Source=WCRDUSMJEMPR9\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=MicroDB;Integrated Security=True"
```

Or escape the slash `"Data Source=WCRDUSMJEMPR9\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=MicroDB;Integrated Security=True"`

Comment: received an "Instance Failure" error, i;m using Visual Studio 2010 (vb)